# jQuery Attribute Selectors OR Operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Here is my `html`:

```
<div id="l">l</div>
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="i">i</div>
```

How to change the color of only the `l` and `a` attributed elements? I searched for a selector with OR, something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('div[id=l,a]').css('color','red');
});
```

It's not working, is there something like that in jQuery?

**EDIT**
Thank you guys it's working now:

```
$('[id=l], [id=a]').css('color', 'red');
```

But what if I want to search for those IDs inside a `<div>` like `$('[id=l], [id=a]','div')`. This doesn't work, how should I do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('#l, #a').css('color','red');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/2Xuat/

Comment: Technically that's an id selector.  Attribute selector would be `$('[id=l], [id=a]').css('color', 'red');` just in case you need it.

Comment: @imoda yes that's exactly what i need, but how to use some rules before them, like div.someClass ?

Comment: add a class if you want, but if you do, you dont even need js, just make the class in css and add it to the respective elements

Comment: @Neal i need that for example if i have inputs i need to select some of them based on their names, but i want to select them based on class they have like $('[id=l], [id=a]','.inputs') this doesn't work

Comment: ... `$('#l, #a, .className')`

Comment: thank you so much Neal but i'm searching for a dynamic solution so i can put either ids or names so i need that in attribute selection way thank you so much for your great help

Comment: @ra_htial: I think you mean `$('.inputs[name="something"], .inputs[name="somethingElse"]')`. Or use `filter`: `$('.inputs').filter('[name="something"], [name="somethingElse"]')`

Comment: @ra_htial, can you explain why you need attribute selection when id is **not** something you would use that for?

Comment: @Felix, i think so too (fix the quotation marks, they are off by a bit)

Comment: Yes got it with .Filter 
i'm working on a complex project so i'm doing a function that i may use either for name or id attributes

Comment: @Neal Yes, in this instance use the #id selector.  I was just saying for other non-class/id attributes.