# Update value of input using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On the page that im working on, there are a lot of hidden inputs:

```
<input a1="2" a2="1" a3="3" name="Value" type="hidden" value="10"> 
<input a1="4" a2="2" a3="6" name="Value" type="hidden" value="12">
<input a1="6" a2="3" a3="9" name="Value" type="hidden" value="14">
...
```

Using the following javascript i want to update the value for some of the inputs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[name="value"]').on('input', function () {
        $('[a1="' + $(this).attr('ds') + '"]').value = $(this).val();
    });
</script>
```

However i want to update the values only for those inputs that have both a1 and a2 equal to $(this).val()

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery attribute selectors OR Operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497883/jquery-attribute-selectors-or-operation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a simple test to check if **both** `a1` **and** `a2` are equals to `$(this).val()`.

This is the code you need:

```
$('[name="value"]').on('input', function () {
    if($(this).attr("a1") == $(this).val() && $(this).attr("a2") == $(this).val()){
       $('[a1="' + $(this).attr('ds') + '"]').value = $(this).val();         
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
 $('[name="value"]').on('input', function () {
     if($(this).attr("a1") == $(this).attr("a2")){
        $('[a1="' + $(this).attr('ds') + '"]').value = $(this).val();         
     }
 });
```

This will perform the update only if the attribute *a1* is equal to attribute *a2*.