# Treat multiple select as single select if the value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$(document).on('change','.custom-select', function(){
    var list = [];
    $('option:selected', $(this)).each(function() {
        list.push($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).find('option').removeAttr("selected");
    console.log(list);
})
```

What I want to achieve is that if the selected value if "Public", it should unselect all and select only public. Only "Public" should be treated as a single select. Rest of the options can be dynamic. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `prop('selected', false)`

```js
$(document).on('change','.custom-select', function(){
    if($('[value="Public"]', this).is(':selected')) {
      $('option:not([value="Public"]):selected', this).prop('selected', false)
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="custom-select" multiple>
  <option value="Public">Public</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can we add an OR? Like the same logic for Public or Contacts? Also get the selected values after this operation.

Comment: @AliZia Sure. you can add `||` or `else if`

Comment: how can I use || inside the $('option:not([value="Public"]):selected', this).prop('selected', false)

Comment: also using else if prioritizes the Public value over Contacts. I don't want that.

Comment: @AliZia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497883/jquery-attribute-selectors-or-operation

Comment: @AliZia Use another if, if `else if` fails

Comment: What I mean is that if I have selected Public and I click on Contacts, it will go in first if and select Public where as I have clicked Contacts. That is something I don't want.